# Objectbox Sync for Flutter

Tags: flutter, objectbox

I'm new to using Objectbox. I've already used the local version of the database ant it works perfectly.

Now I want to understand how Objectbox Sync work if I still haven't obtained the Sync Server version. I tried to set up my entities in the Sync mode, but when I run the app, errors are thrown stating that the sever isn't available yet. Does Objectbox use a local database in case the server isn't available? How can I initially set up my entities and work on the app until I get the Sync Server?  Thank you in advance.

I tried to run the app in the sync mode without the server, but errors are thrown.

Comment: If not resolved already, you should be able to use ObjectBox as long as you don't use any Sync APIs (e.g. Sync.client).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Uwe - ObjectBox. I'm actually in the development phase and was just wondering if I can set up my entities in the sync mode even if I don't have yet got the sync server. As for using the ObjectBox in the offline mode, it works fine.

Comment: Maybe this helps: it is not possible to change an entity from not synced to synced or the other way. The database would have to be deleted.